# Return type of a function based on param name

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an interface `MyInterface` like this:

```
interface MyInterface = {
    param1: string;
    param2: number;
}
```

Is there a way declare the return type of a function, given that the value of the parameter of the function is in itself a parameter of `MyInterface`:

```
class MyClass<T = MyInterface> {
   constructor(private params: T) {
     // ...
   }

    // The question comes here:
   get(value: keyof T): T[value] { // Obviously this doesn't work
      return this.params[value];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the type of `value` e.g. using another generic:

```
type MyInterface = {
    param1: string;
    param2: number;
}

class MyClass<T = MyInterface> {
   constructor(private params: T) {
     // ...
   }

   // Fixed 
   get<G extends keyof T>(value:G): T[G] {
      return this.params[value];
   }
}
```